# grab td third value using jinja loopindex

Tags: jquery, python

I'm using flask python with some jquery. I'm not good at jquery at all. anyway, I have created two loops and they return values very well but my problem is how to get rowloop of jinja and assign it to var in jquery and then display the fifth td.

my code is:

```
{% for value in plugin_data %}
<tr id="sub_vlaues_table">
<td class="box-star"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag-o text-red"></i></a></td>
{% set rowloop = loop %}
{% for subvalue in value %}
<td id="td_{{loop.index0}}_{{rowloop.index}}">{{ subvalue }}</td>
{% endfor %}
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

result : it actually assign a unique number to the td ID as below:

```
<td id="td_1_5">jqs.exe</td>
```

number 1 is : loop.index0
number 5 is : rowloop.index

here is Jquery code:

```
$(".box-star").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //detect type
  var $this = $(this).find("a > i");
  var fa = $this.hasClass("fa");


  if (fa) {
    $this.toggleClass("fa-flag");
    $this.toggleClass("fa-flag-o");
        $(this).find('#tdvalue_0').each (function() {
            var value = $('#tdvalue_0').text();
            alert(value);
        });

   }
});
```